# One radio button that updates four others using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table with four radio buttons.

```
                     Off On   Off On
                            | (0)(0) Visibility part 1
(Global Visibility)  (0)(0) | (0)(0) Visibility part 2
                            | (0)(0) Visibility part 3
                            | (0)(0) Visibility part 4
```

I want to make it so when you click off and on for global visibility, it updates the other parts.

How would I go about doing that?

Here is a JS fiddle link!
http://jsfiddle.net/2admbx90/1/

Comment: You should post the html and the javascript you have so far.

Comment: What did you try? You`ll want to use JavaScript. If you also want to store data on the back end you'll use AJAX, which is JavaScript that can send data to and receive data from PHP, which you'll probably end up using MySQL with.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you would use a radio button instead of a regular button, but here is a JSfiddle that does what you want. You will want to load jQuery for ease of coding, and then just use the .toggle() function on the element containing the children selectors.
http://jsfiddle.net/qa7gr5r7/
**JS**

```
function hideChildren() {
    $('#two').toggle();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="one">
    <input type='button' value="Toggle" name="button" onclick="hideChildren();"></input>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <input type='radio' name="children" value="1">1</input>
    <input type='radio' name="children" value="2">2</input>
    <input type='radio' name="children" value="3">3</input>
    <input type='radio' name="children" value="4">4</input>
</div>
```

There are most likely, much better ways of doing this like iteratively removing children elements so they are not POSTed if this is part of a form, but this allows you to hide and unhide at will one containing element, in this case a DIV with id='two'.